# Assert.AreEqual() giving unreliable results

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have the following test:

```
Assert.AreEqual(descendants.Count(), 2);
```

It always passes when I run it alone but fails if I run it with all the other tests. Every time it fails is tells me that it is expecting an Expected value of 0 - even though my code clearly tells it to expect a value of 2:

> Message:
> Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<0>. Actual:<2>.

Edit - To be clear descendants.Count() always returns 2 like it should. Sometimes Assert.AreEqual is trying expecting the value 2 and sometimes it is expecting the value 0 - even though I have expected value of 2 in my statement.

What is happening here?

Comment: What test framework? NUnit? If so, you have the method arguments backwards: `expected` comes first ([source](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/assertions/classic-assertions/Assert.AreEqual.html)). Better yet, use the new style of assertions: `Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected));`

Comment: Sounds like `descendants` is being modified in other unit tests. You'll need to post more code, otherwise this is a guessing game, i.e., how is `descendants` being used throughout the test? Is `descendants` being used in other tests? etc... Also, `descendants` should be using `.length` or `.Count`, re: `.Count()` is a linq expression and is not evaluated until the Assert is invoked.

Comment: Post the test class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eric.
There is a link about Assert.AreEqual [Assert.AreEqual](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/assertions/classic-assertions/Assert.AreEqual.html)

The first parameter - descendants.Count() - expected

the second parameter - actual (2)

it should be in an opposite way, like

```
Assert.AreEqual(2,descendants.Count());
```

Comment: Doesn't matter if the parameters are in the wrong position. Either 2 ==2 or 2 != 2. Same numbers

Comment: @MetroSmurf: It won't matter for whether the assert fails or not. It does matter for what is written in the error message, and that is what confused the OP. Their method returns `0`. The correct solution is to (a) follow the advice in this answer (which is 100% correct) and then (b) find out why OP's method returns 0 (which is something only OP can do).

Comment: @Heinzi the positional arguments are immaterial for the OP, re: `always passes when I run it alone but fails if I run it with all the other tests`. Yes, the OP should be using actual and expected appropriately, but the question is why does `descendants` have a different value when run in isolation vs when run with all other tests.

Comment: @MetroSmurf: Good point. Nevertheless, OP also asked *"Every time it fails is tells me that it is expecting an Expected value of 0 - even though my code clearly tells it to expect a value of 2"*, the reason of which is correctly answered in this answer. OP's other problem can't be solved here without a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I see the issue.

1. Yes, I have my expected value and actual value backwards. That was causing my confusion.
2. A previous test WAS modifying my variable db. I changed an underlying field in the class to static. Before the values of the underlying field did not persist. Now they do. This is one good reason for running tests - to insure that changes that we make don't create unanticipated results.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a race condition? Race conditions in software or any system occur when the desired output requires that certain events occur in a specific order but that the events don’t always happen in that order. There is a ‘race’ between the events and if the wrong events win, the program fails. Usually happens in multi-thread applications.